# read & extract information from it to use with other variables in code?

Tags: python, json, configuration-files

I have a code that requires a lot of variable configurations. We want to be open to select a `json` file from the dialog box that contains all the configurations by their variable name and then once you click `'start'` the program will run and utilize the configs from the file versus the user hard coding them into the `.py` file every single time.

For clarity, the file I want to open is named `test.json` & within it, there are 5 different dictionaries that contain the corresponding variables.

What I need the `json` to load is the input piece and load the file associated with this.

I know I can just select the actual file, but we're trying to see if this possible to load a configuration file that does this.

sample of `test.json`

```
{
    "input":["test.dat"],
    "preprocessing": {
        "a": "svdrecon",
        "b": -110,
        "b":  -90,
        "d": 256,
        "e":   4,
        "e": 512
    }
```

`"input":["test.dat"]`

my `open_file` method is as follows

````
def open_file(self):
        self.filename, dummy = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName (self, "Open file", "", "I/Q Files (*.bin *.dat *.ltd *.json *.wrp);;Everything (*)")
        self.statusbar.showMessage("Current File Selected: " + self.filename)
        self.strtbtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.cnclbtn.setEnabled(True)

        #load json
        with open(filename) as filename:
            config = json.load(filename)
        #parse data
        #extract input filename
        filename = (config['input'])```
````

Comment: A representative sample of `test.json` is missing.

Comment: I only included the first line of it, but I added a bit more for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

> `"input":["test.dat"]`

The value of this JSON name–value pair is an array with one string element, which gets loaded as a list of one string. If you want to get only a string from `config['input']`, you can either put `"input": "test.dat"` into `test.json`, or extract the (first) string from the list with `config['input'][0]`.

Comment: I'm still getting an error that it's an invalid object. File "./test.py", line 54, in run
    file = ww.nloader([self.filename])
RuntimeError: invalid object; expected filename but instead got...

Comment: Remove the brackets from _ww.nloader([self.filename])_. They make a list out of what should remain a string.

Comment: In the future, if we were to pass it more than 1 file/variable, would the brackets go back ?

Comment: If you've removed the brackets from the `"input"` value in `test.json`, yes, those would _go back_. The brackets in _ww.nloader(…)_ can never go back, since this function doesn't accept a list; if you want to process more than 1 file therewith, you have to loop.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

```
def open_file(self):
    jsonfile, dummy = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName (self, "Open file", "", "I/Q Files (*.bin *.dat *.ltd *.json *.wrp);;Everything (*)")
    self.statusbar.showMessage("Current File Selected: " + self.filename)
    self.strtbtn.setEnabled(True)
    self.cnclbtn.setEnabled(True)

with open(jsonfile) as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    self.filename = (config['input'])
```